# Google apps script sheet, check index of a cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to send a multi-step web form to a Google sheet, using Google apps script and Ajax.

And because it's a public form and in multi-steps, I want to save the second ajax request to the same row as the first ajax request. And to avoid duplicated submissions, I save a unique id in the first time and check against it in the next submissions.

**Assuming this is the sheet structure:**

```
Timestamp        step1-col        step2-col         uniqueId
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1547266627717    step1-data       step2-data        1234
```

**My code in GAS as follows:**

```
var uniqueIdColIndex = 4, step2ColIndex = 3;

function doGet(e) {
    return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
    var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
    lock.waitLock(30000);

    try {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
        var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
        var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
        var row = [];

        //make a search for the uniqueId;
        var uniqueIdColValues = sheet.getRange(2, uniqueIdColIndex, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues()[0];
        var uniqueIdRowIndex = uniqueIdColValues.indexOf(e.parameters.uniqueId);

        //if the uniqueId were saved before:
        if (uniqueIdRowIndex > -1) { //<--- this always fail! why?
            //make another search for the step2-value;
            var step2Data = sheet.getRange(uniqueIdColIndex + 1, step2ColIndex).getValues()[0];

            //if the step2-data wasn't saved before, save it;
            if (!step2Data) {
                sheet.getRange(uniqueIdColIndex + 1, step2ColIndex).setValues([e.parameters.step2data]);

                // return a json success results
                return ContentService
                        .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result": "success", "row": nextRow}))
                        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
            }

            //else: continue writing the form to the sheet;
        } else {
            //loop through the header columns
            for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                if (headers[i] === "Timestamp") { //save a 'Timestamp'
                    row.push(new Date().getTime());
                } else { //else use the header names to get data
                    if (!e.parameters[headers[i]]) {
                        row.push('');
                    } else {
                        row.push(e.parameters[headers[i]]);
                    }
                }
            }
            //save the data for the first step;
            sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

            //return a json success
            return ContentService
                    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result": "success", "row": nextRow}))
                    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
        }

    } catch (e) {
        // if error return this
        return ContentService
                .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result": "error", "error": e}))
                .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

    } finally { //release lock
        lock.releaseLock();
    }

}
```

## The problem is:

I always end up getting duplicated submissions in 2 rows like so:

```
Timestamp        step1-col        step2-col         uniqueId
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1547266627717    step1-data                         1234
1547266647568                     step2-data        1234
```

Which happens because my `uniqueId` check always fails, I guess.

What am I doing wrong?

And how can I merge both steps/ajax requests to the same row?

Comment: You mean the Ajax code or the GAS attached code?

Comment: GAS code. There's no method called `getPublicLock()` in documentation.

Comment: Well, I haven't wrote it from scratch, I'm modifying another person's code, so, I didn't care much about `getPublicLock()`, because I'm not familiar enough with GAS, and I didn't thought it's something to care about, but thanks for the hint, sure, I'll check it out.

Comment: About the `indexOf`: Thanks for the link. 
I checked it out, and my question is: if `getValues()` returns an array of arrays (2D array), wouldn't this give me an array like this: `[[1234]]` ? 

If that's true, I'm trying to access its first array when I wrote `.getValues()[0]` ... So, isn't this supposed to get me the index already?

Comment: I guess you're right. 1. Can you try `e.parameter.uniqueId` instead? (parameters will provide a array and `indexOf` is strict) 2. If that doesn't work, You need to provide logs.